# Having trouble with opening Excel file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Pandas for the 1st time and don't know much about it.
While trying to read an Excel file, Visual Studio code shows the *"missing dependency xlrd"*. I don't know what to do.

*Info:*

Anaconda, VS code installed on the same drive. Excel file also on the same drive. I am using Windows 10 64bit.

[image: Please refer the screenshot below]

Comment: try pip install pandas in command promt

Comment: [pip install xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/)

Comment: please add more details

Comment: cmd -"Requirement already satsified"

Comment: Try this: sudo pip3 install xlrd

Comment: try `conda install -c anaconda xlrd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short description. It would be nice if the description was a little more detailed. Try install the module:

```
pip install xlrd
```

If using python3 then:

```
pip3 install xlrd
```

If you are using conda:

```
conda install -c anaconda xlrd
```

May be there are multiple python versions in the system, where requirement might be satisfied for one and not for the other. I faced such problem and `python3` rather than `pip3` worked for me. Check out this too.

```
python3 -m pip install xlrd
```

Then it must work, otherwise, upgrade.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
pip3 install --upgrade xlrd
```

I hope this will work.

```py
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

sp = pd.ExcelFile("data.xlsx")
print(sp.parse(sp.sheet_names[0]))
```

If it doesn't work even after the upgrade, my guess is that there is another problem that is not known from your description. (Please include the full error message in the description as a code block, not in image format.)

Comment: Thanks. Due to my incomplete knowledge, I wrote the pip install xlrd in jupyter cell instead in command prompt. Fortunately, it ran and asked me to restart the kermel, which I did. Now it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you have all the required libraries installed.

```
pip install pandas
```

Pandas also requires the NumPy library

```
pip install numpy
```

In order to work with Pandas in your script, you will need to import it into your code. This is done with one line of code:

```
import pandas as pd
```

To work with Excel using Pandas, you need an additional object named ExcelFile. ExcelFile is built into the Pandas ecosystem, so you import directly from Pandas:

```
from pandas import ExcelFile
```

Recall your path where you have that excel file, example: /Users/Desktop/file.xlsx
Rather than referencing the path inside of the Read_Excel function, keep code clean by storing the path in a variable:

```
file_path = '/Users/Desktop/file.xlsx'
```

The Read_Excel function takes the file path of an Excel Workbook and returns a DataFrame object with the contents.

Put it all together and set the DataFrame object to a variable named “df”:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_Path)
```

Lastly, you want to view the DataFrame so print the result. Add a print statement to the end of your script, using the DataFrame variable as the argument

```
print(df)
```